# Joining two selects - different column names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union

I need to build a SELECT statement showing all columns for JV1 - JV6.

How would I go about getting JV2, JV3, etc populated?

```
SELECT 
Id as [JV1],
vp_pct  as [JV1 Per],
vl_role  as [JV1 Role],
[status]  as [JV1 Status]
FROM era_project_allications_m
WHERE era_project_allications_m.jv_row_id = '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
Id as [JV2],
vp_pct  as [JV2 Per],
vl_role  as [JV2 Role],
[status]  as [JV2 Status]
FROM era_project_allications_m
WHERE era_project_allications_m.jv_row_id = '2'
```

I need the results to display columns containing the JV1, JV2 information.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You really need to provide some details here for people to help. It sounds like you want to use a cross tab or PIVOT.

Comment: could you please paste as text,images will be blocked in some domains

Comment: Join an union are 2 different things. You can't have different column names in union but you can add a column that will hold the source table name (hard coded) to help you understand where the row comes from,

Comment: Looks like the best solution would be to join the two selects together?

Comment: Could you show an example of the table and output required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Figured this one out.

I simply used 6 select statements, giving them each an aliases and a unique ID (project ID as Select_1_ID, Select_2_ID) and LEFT JOIN'd them together using the Select 1's ID).

Rather long-winded but it works - I suspect it isn't very efficient though, Thankfully it only returns 24k rows.

Answer (score 4):

Join and union are 2 different things. You can't have different column names in union but you can add a column that will hold the source table name (hard coded) to help you understand where the row comes from:

```
SELECT 
Id,
vp_pct,
vl_role,
[status],
'1' as sourceId
FROM era_project_allications_m
WHERE jv_row_id = '1'

UNION ALL

SELECT 
Id,
vp_pct,
vl_role,
[status],
'2'
FROM era_project_allications_m
WHERE jv_row_id = '2'
```

though based on your sample code you might just want to do this:

```
SELECT 
Id,
vp_pct,
vl_role,
[status],
jv_row_id as sourceId
FROM era_project_allications_m
WHERE jv_row_id IN('1', '2'...'n')
```

Comment: I need to display the each row based on it's jv_row_id in different columns specifically.